# Restoring cassandra from snapshot

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

So I did something of a test run/disaster recovery practice deleting a table and restoring in Cassandra via snapshot on a test cluster I have built.

This test cluster has four nodes, and I used the node restart method so after truncating the table in question, all nodes were shutdown, commitlog directories cleared, and the current snapshot data copied back into the table directory for each node.  Afterwards, I brought each node back up.  Then following the documentation I ran a repair on each node, followed by a refresh on each node.

My question is, why is it necessary for me to run a repair on each node afterwards assuming none of the nodes were down except when I shut them down to perform the restore procedure? (in this test instance it was a small amount of data and took very little time to repair, if this happened in our production environment the repairs would take about 12 hours to perform so this could be a HUGE issue for us in a disaster scenario).

And I assume running the repair would be completely unnecessary on a single node instance, correct?

Just trying to figure out what the purpose of running the repair and subsequent refresh is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is repair?

Repair is one of Cassandra's main anti-entropy mechanisms. Essentially it ensures that all your nodes have the latest version of all the data. The reason it takes 12 hours (this is normal by the way) is that it is an expensive operation -- io and CPU intensive -- to generate merkel trees for all your data, compare them with merkel trees from other nodes, and stream any missing / outdated data.

#### Why run a repair after a restoring from snapshots

Repair gives you a consistency baseline. For Example: If the snapshots weren't taken at the exact same time, you have a chance of reading stale data if you're using CL ONE and hit a replica restored from the older snapshot. Repair ensures all your replicas are up to date with the latest data available.

### tl;dr:

> repairs would take about 12 hours to perform so this could be a HUGE
> issue for us in a disaster scenario).

While your repair is running, you'll have some risk of reading stale data if your snapshots don't have the same exact data. If they are old snapshots, gc_grace may have already passed for some tombstones giving you a higher risk of zombie data if tombstones aren't well propagated across your cluster.

#### Related side rant - When to run a repair?

The coloquial definition of the term repair seems to imply that your system is broken. We think "I have to run a repair? I must have done something wrong to get to this *un-repaired* state!" This is simply not true. Repair is a normal maintenance operation with Cassandra. In fact, you should be running repair at least every gc_grace seconds to ensure data consistency and avoid zombie data (or use the [opscenter repair service](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/online_help/services/repairService.html)).

In my opinion, we should have called it `AntiEntropyMaintenence` or `CassandraOilChange` or something rather than `Repair` : )